# How do I concatenate a variable in angular.element?

Tags: angularjs

I currently have this, but I am unable to say concatenate a variable in the middle.

`var popoverElement = angular.element('<div class="myPopover hide">  [need my variable here] </div>');`

Comment: I would question why you need to do this in the first place but you probably just want to use concatenation

Comment: I have a use-case, was using angular.translate and got the value via promise.

Comment: variable value or binded variable?

Comment: do you want scope variable there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation:

```
var popoverElement = angular.element('<div class="myPopover hide">' + var + '</div>');
```